# Failed to read JSON file using $http.get in angular script on Rails and Undefined $scope

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

Q1: I have the following code:

```
  <script>
    function ProductionIndexCtrl($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('POD.json').success(function(data) {
                  $scope.results = data.results;
                  console.log("Here");
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('error');
                });
              };
  </script>
```

That attempts to open POD.json which I have provided in the same directory as index.html.
I am currently running this on rails and both files are under the app/assets/templates/production folder. But everytime I run this controller, I fail; to read from POD.json. The rest of the page renders fine.

I know that there are rules for certain browsers and that firefox allows from localfile reading and I am using Firefox to test my results, but still no luck.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Any ideas?

---

Q2:

Hi! I have the following code js.coffee:

```
@temp.controller 'ProductionCtrl', [
'$scope', 
'$http', 
(($scope, $http) ->

$scope.results = 
[
  {
    "name": "1",
    "location": "a",
    "status": "g",
    "size": "3551"
  }
]
```

But it seems that everytime I run it, I get an error for $scope not defined. 
I have included ng-app at the top of my views html file, and my ng-controller directive around the $scope that I want to include. But it seems that I am still missing something. Any ideas?